# 2 kendo ui treeview in same page not expanded nodes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am trying to put 2 kendo ui treeviews in same page. 
The Page is Rendered fine but i can't expand the nodes of the trees.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You must provide different names to the .Name() attribute of the treeviews in order to let it expand because onclicking node items it distracts one another..

Answer (score 0):

Check your page for JavaScript errors. Those would prevent the Kendo UI widgets from working as expected. Here is a list of common JS errors: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/troubleshooting#known-javascript-errors